# Understanding Parsing YAML

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm trying to understand how YAML works and I'm working from examples in a book to learn it. Here's the code I'm using:

```
require "yaml"

def savelist(songs, playlist)
    File.open playlist, 'w' do |f|
        f.write(songs.to_yaml)
    end
end

def openlist(playlist)
    loadlist = File.read playlist
    YAML::load loadlist
end

podcasts = Dir['C:/Users/7/Music/Amazon MP3/*.mp3']

puts "Welcome to the Playlist Maker!"

list = 'playlist.txt'

savelist(podcasts, list)

openlist(list)
```

I thought the second method, openlist, would actually call the file to the screen and print out its contents. I read it as "create a loadlist object then **load** the object to the screen with YAML". I expected it to print the file contents (YAML::load).

The program works, but I don't really understand how it works. I'm also not really sure what the second method is there for if it doesn't actually open the file.

Thanks for your insight. I sorta get what YAML does, but I don't really know how or why this works.

Comment: Load the object to the screen? Usually you *print* to the screen, and *load* stuff into memory. That's what load does-it parses the yaml file into an object in memory. It returns that object, and that's what you're seeing despite not explicitly printing it.

Comment: Kudos (and rep) to both answerers. It's important to learn how to learn how stuff works. I'd argue it's *the* critical skill.

Comment: That was exactly my thought, "why not just use 'print'?" so I just ran the code as is, and when it didn't print I wasn't sure exactly what it did. The responses below give me some insight I need to understand it. Thanks everyone for your help. Making things work is one thing, but understanding how enables me to write better code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
require "yaml"

def savelist(songs, playlist)
  File.write(playlist, songs.to_yaml)
end

def openlist(playlist)
  YAML::load_file(playlist)
end
```

---

Learning how YAML works is easier if you look at what it's emitting, and play with it in IRB:

```
>> require 'yaml'
false
>> songs = ['foo', 'bar']
[
    [0] "foo",
    [1] "bar"
]
>> puts songs.to_yaml
---
- foo
- bar
nil
>>
>> yaml = songs.to_yaml
"---\n- foo\n- bar\n"
>> YAML::load(yaml)
[
    [0] "foo",
    [1] "bar"
]
```

YAML is just text, so writing a YAML file is simple if you use `write`, as I did above. YAML has a convenient method `load_file` to read a file, then parse it back into the equivalent Ruby object. If you've already read the file into a variable, then use `load` to parse it and return the Ruby object.

Playing with YAML this way, by converting an array or hash to YAML, then using `load` to mess with it, is a great way to learn it. [The YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org) is useful once you start to get an idea how it works, but doing the "round-trip" thing is how to boot-strap yourself. (This is also useful when learning about JSON.)

We actually use a variation of this when initially defining complex YAML files. I'll write a bit of Ruby code with the object defined inside it, then save that to a file. From that point on we can tweak the YAML, or, as I prefer, we tweak the Ruby and re-create the YAML. Using the Ruby code to recreate the file means we've got a fall-back if someone hoses the configuration. At least we can rebuild our default setup.

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely helpful. I think it's a matter of just understanding coding vocabulary. I see "load" and I think (as an amateur coder) the file will open/print it's contents, but that makes sense that it's just loading to the object not the screen.

Comment: I've never used a language that used `load` to open, read and print its contents, at least I don't remember it. Languages often have very atomic (low-level) commands, and then more and more convenient and higher-level commands are built using them. This allows us to pick between convenience and flexibility and control since seldom does a high-level command offer the same control as using the low-level ones. It's easy to create a command that does what you're saying: `puts File.read('path/to/foo')` is a simple example, so having a Ruby method that does it all makes no real sense.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I guess I'm coming from a more amateur perspective. The only other language I know is English and when I use the term "load" in that language, say to load a game or a document, it opens the game/document onto my screen. Of course I also understand this isn't the case for programming. Hence the question about how the term "load" works here.These granular explanations of terminology help me better contextualize what's happening. You guys gave a lot of new knowledge here today so I'll continue building this little program and probably post for review on Code.

Comment: "...when I use the term "load" in that language, say to load a game or a document, it opens the game/document onto my screen." You'll find that every technology has its own use for terms that can differ wildly from what a layman's spoken language thinks that word means. It's part of learning a technology. Even programming languages can use terms differently, or different terms for the same data structures. It's just the result of people trying to find words to describe a concept.

Answer (score 1):

Let's step through this and see how we might learn what a block of code does.

```
def openlist(playlist)
    loadlist = File.read playlist
    YAML::load loadlist
end
```

For starters we're passing some `playlist` object to `File.read`. We can look up the [`File`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html) class but we won't find a `read` method on it. We will however see that `File` is a subclass of `IO` and if we look at `IO` we will find [`IO.read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-read)

```
read(name, [length [, offset]] ) → string
```

So `read` takes a file name and an optional length and offset and returns a string. `loadlist` is then just a string containing the contents of this file. Useful but not easy for us to work with yet.

If we look up the [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) module we learn that it is a wrapper around `Psych` where we can finally find [`load`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load)

```
load(yaml, filename = nil)
Load yaml in to a Ruby data structure...
```

So `load` takes some string and returns a Ruby data structure created by parsing the YAML syntax it contains.

Now we see why this example is using two different methods, one to load the contents of a file and one to parse those into a Ruby data structure. While we're looking at `Psych` we might also notice the `load_file` method which gives us another way to do the same thing as @the-tin-man suggested.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I read through the rubydocs page but the definitions don't always help me understand what's going on.